# Why isn't Apollo Server a middleware for Express, rather than being a server that accepts Express as a middleware?

Tags: express, graphql, middleware, apollo

I'm just wondering what's the reason for this seemingly awkward configuration (from [Getting Started w/ Apollo Server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started.html)),

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  // These will be defined for both new or existing servers
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app }); // app is from an existing express app
```

Why is that I'm calling `.applyMiddleware()` and feeding it my `app` rather than using [`app.use()`](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html), it even seems from the docs that Apollo  is only answering requests on `/graphql` wouldn't it be better to follow the Express API of,

```
let apollo = require('apollo-server').ApolloMiddleware
app.use( '/graphql', apollo({ typeDefs, resolvers }) );
```

It seems like Apollo is inverting the normal middleware flow of Express? What is the advantage of doing it the Apollo way?

Answer (score 2):

I don't work with those guys, but based off the code that is there, I assume it has to do with the fact that it adds body-parser, upload capability, websockets (if you opt into this one) to the app, as well as a .well-known configuration for engine's health checks. The well-known would have to be at root according to that spec. Additionally, if you're using the subscriptions and websockets, they listen for `httpServer.once('listening')`, so they have to have access to your app. If they simply handed you one that you could mount, you wouldn't `app.listen` on it, since you'd `app.listen` on your own instead.

Just from the internals, this is what I would expect, at least.