# Apollo-Server, how to use it with SailsJS?

Tags: express, sails.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I don't understand how to use an Apollo-Server with an app like `Sails.JS` (`Express` based).

Apollo-Server's Readme (https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server#express) states an `Express` app requires this code:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });
```

But **why**? And **how** do you use this in `Sails.JS`?

Why we can't we use this code instead? :

```
let apollo = require('apollo-server').ApolloMiddleware
app.use( '/graphql', apollo({ typeDefs, resolvers }) );
```

I'm not the only one having this issue: [Why isn't Apollo Server a middleware for Express, rather than being a server that accepts Express as a middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716013/why-isnt-apollo-server-a-middleware-for-express-rather-than-being-a-server-tha)

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend using `apollo-server` with Sails.JS. If you're going to be doing something like that, I would recommend using node's `graphql` library directly and adding your own endpoint. `apollo-server` simply tries to do too many things that Sails is already doing for you, and vice-versa. It doesn't really do that many things that you can't easily plug it in with your own middleware. Sorry, and good luck.